# Back key on activity is delivered to caller

Tags: android, android-activity, back

I have activity A wich calls activity B with startActivityForResult.

I'm handling the result with onActivityResult which executes an action X to refresh activity A.

The problem is that when the user presses the back key in activity B the action executed in activity A is canceled because it is handling the back key event.

That is, the back key event is being handled also in activity A... why?

The app is targeted to API 4.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that your Activity A is also being removed from the Activity stack when back is pressed from Activity B?

Comment: No, a handler in activity A also receives the back key event that finnished activity B.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to solve this is to redefine [onKeyDown() / onKeyUp()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) calls in your activity B, and do not call super.onKeyDown() when you receive Back key, just finishActivity()

Comment: It doesn't work...
I added
`@Override
 public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
   finish();
   return true;
  } else {
   return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
  }
 }
`
and activity A also receives the back key event.